# Java Private video YouTube

Tags: java, video, youtube-api

I have an application in GWT and i would like to view a private YouTube video programmatically (which I uploaded).

After reading the documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java

and the following forums:

- http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=520
- http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=872
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/PXw1dMPkBSM

I realized that it isn't possible!!

Given this context, my question is:

Is there any workaround?

Thanks.